# How to open the settings of the Python Interpreter of a virtualenv in PyCharm on windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and want to run pytests within a virtual environment using PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition) on Windows 10. I think I managed to add a virtual environment as a new "Python Interpreter", but now when I want to get to the "Interpreter Settings" or to "Manage Packages" in the environment of the project named "TAF" nothing happens:

[image]

This is what I see on the lower right of the PyCharm window. Clicking on "Interpreter Settings" or "Manage Packages" seems to have no action.

Is there something I am doing wrong/have to enable...?